# Embedding metric spaces into Hilbert ones

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hilbert-spaces

Does every compact metric space continuously embed into a Hilbert space (possibly with large distortion)?

Comment: All compact metric spaces embeds into the Hilbert cube, which itself embeds into the Hilbert space.

Comment: Thanks! Reference?

Comment: Honestly, both are Wikipedia:) but the second one is an explicit construction while the first one is: wlog the diameter of $K$ isless than $1$; choose countable dense set $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ and map $x$ to $(d(x, x_1), d(x, x_2), \ldots)$. This is a continuous injection from compact set into Hilbert cube, hence homeomorphism.

Comment: @AlekseiKulikov This seems to only require separability and boundedness -- is compactness really necessary?

Comment: Indeed, I see that Urysohn's metrization theorem removes the compactness (and even boundedness) assumptions.

Comment: @AryehKontorovich Compactness is not needed, actually every Polish space embeds into the Hilbert cube (even more: a space is Polish iff it is homeomorphic to a $G_\delta$ subset of the Hilbert cube). Boundedness is irrelevant because any metric space is homeomorphic to a bounded metric space

Comment: You cannot embed with the finite distortion in the general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may also send $X$ into a space $L_2(X,\mu)$ via the Fréchet-Kuratowski isometry $x\mapsto d(\cdot,x)\in C^0(X),\|\cdot\|_\infty$, followed by the bounded linear inclusion $C^0(X)\to L_2(X,\mu)$, where $\mu$ is a probability measure on $X$. If $\text{supp}(\mu)=X$ (e.g. $\mu$ is a series of deltas $\sum_{k=1}^\infty2^{-k}\delta_{q_k}$ for a dense set $\{q_k\}_{k\ge1}$), then $C^0(X)\to L_2(X,\mu)$ is injective, and the composition $j:X\to L_2(X,\mu)$ is a continuous embedding (a homeo  of $X$ with $j(X)$).